# View knowledge about ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I need to connect methods in View (WPF window) to events in ViewModel. Is it violation of MVVM pattern to DirectCast Object DataContext in view to concrete VM type and connect its events? If yes, is there better way to do it?

Comment: What type of methods are you looking to connect? Are they events?

Comment: 1) expose commands on VM 2) add command properties on the view 3) bind them and 4) execute them from your view when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at what the methods in the view do. If they manipulate the view, consider adding properties to the viewmodel that you change in the events in the viewmodel and bind the view to. This way, by binding the view to properties you eliminate the need for code in the view.

If the methods contain other logic consider moving that logic to the viewmodel.

In other cases casting a DataContext to a viewmodel or interface can be a valid option and is not a violation of the MVVM pattern.

When adding code to a view, do consider testing. Automated/unit testing a view is harder than testing a viewmodel.

Comment: Events are exposed in my VM because: VM needs filename selected in SaveFileDialog (which is shown by View) and VM needs confirmation of some action using MessageBox (also shown by View). Usual actions in VM like saving changes or reading data are exposed via ICommands.

Comment: You could create a viewservice that shows the dialog and returns the result (file name, ok/cancel) And call the service in the view model.

Comment: Creating some ViewService/DialogService is unnecessary and does not bring any advantages over my solution.

Comment: It does. The view service can easily be stubbed by a mock so you can test the view model with out being dependent on a click on a dialog button

Comment: I can attach method which simulates what user clicked to that event and it will be three times easier than your mocking.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a violation of the MVVM pattern, but the more abstract the better, of course (not because of MVVM but as a general good practice).

If you're setting your DataContext on XAML, you may be able to keep it abstract by using Interactivity `EventTrigger` and `CallMethodAction`... Maybe. But if you're setting it on code-behind (via injection or whatever), you're left with either casting the DataContext to a known type, or using Reflection (I wouldn't >_>).

Generally, creating an interface for your ViewModel, so you keep a decent level of abstraction and only expose what the view needs to know instead of its whole implementation, is good enough for most scenarios.

```
public interface IMyViewModel
{
    event EventHandler MyEvent;
}

public class MyViewModel : IMyViewModel
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    // More viewmodel related stuff

    protected virtual void OnMyEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyEvent != null)
            MyEvent(this, e);
    }
}

public class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyWindow(IMyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
        (this.DataContext as IViewModel).MyEvent += MyEventHandler;
    }

    private void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do view related stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't use interface for abstraction, because my VMs contains lot of very different members so I can't create something common for everything.